# Extract Text from Flattenned PDF created with ItextSharp Or PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I want to retrieve some data from many PDFs that were created from a certain template, that i have, with ItextSharp.

Those PDFs were Flattened

```
FormFlattening = true;
```

I have tried many different aproaches that i have found on the internet and none has worked. I get an error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Stack empty.'
```

Always when i try to extract, usually at the following line no matter the strategy:

```
string thePage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy);
```

I tryed also pdfSharp with no luck and no real documentation on extracting.
Also i tried and two libraries that use IKVM  but those cant work on my project.

Edit 1 : My current workaround is using pdftotext.exe from Xpdf, calling it as a process and then reading the txt file. This is somewhat slow.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample PDF https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5FPBMCoTTRW5iq68pRnUN__QFI_0jVX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are libraries that can extract the text from your PDF file but asking for a recommendation is a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: AIUI you are not using PDFsharp to create the PDF files, so IMHO your title is misleading. You do not show any PDFsharp code, so why do you use the PDFsharp tag?

Comment: Vive la déraison. I say extract with  iTextSharp OR pdfsharp. Meaning i just want to extract the data with either one of those.. I even say it in my answer. The main problem as you can see is not the HOW i can extract the values. But why they are not getting extracted. And mkl gave an awesome answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short

The reason for that exception is an error in the PDF. Some of the appearance streams flattened into the content contain two end-marked-content operations for a single begin-marked-content operation. In the associated `IContentOperator` implementation that second **EMC** causes an exception. By wrapping that implementation in one that suppresses these exceptions, you can extract the text.

#### The error

Some of the appearance streams flattened into the content contain two end-marked-content operations for a single begin-marked-content operation.

E.g. the former appearance stream flattened as form Xobject **Xi8** looks like this:

```
/Tx BMC
q
 1.00 1.00 130.91 29.51 re
W
n
0.00 g

BT
/ArialMT 14.00 Tf
2 10.90 Td
 15.62 TL
(\b\tüü\b) Tj
ET
Q
EMC
EMC
```

The `IContentOperator` implementation associated with **EMC** operations simply does a

```
markedContentStack.Pop();
```

which in case of the second **EMC** with an empty `markedContentStack` causes the `InvalidOperationException`.

#### A work-around

You can prevent this error situation from stopping the text extraction by wrapping that **EMC** `IContentOperator` implementation in one that suppresses these exceptions.

E.g. use this helper class

```
public class InvalidOperationExceptionIgnoringWrapper : IContentOperator
{
    public void Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List<PdfObject> operands)
    {
        try
        {
            WrappedOperator.Invoke(processor, oper, operands);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Caught InvalidOperationException {0} for {1}", e.Message, oper);
        }
    }

    public IContentOperator WrappedOperator { get; set; }
}
```

as follows:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"SamplePDF.pdf");
int pageNumber = 1;

PdfDictionary pageDic = pdfReader.GetPageN(pageNumber);
PdfDictionary resourcesDic = pageDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

ITextExtractionStrategy renderListener = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(renderListener);

InvalidOperationExceptionIgnoringWrapper wrapper = new InvalidOperationExceptionIgnoringWrapper();
IContentOperator original = processor.RegisterContentOperator("EMC", wrapper);
wrapper.WrappedOperator = original;

processor.ProcessContent(ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesForPage(pdfReader, pageNumber), resourcesDic);

var pageText = renderListener.GetResultantText();
```

Now the text extracts with four InvalidOperationExceptions suppressed.

---

This actually is no final *fix* or *solution*, only a *work-around*, because the **actual error is in the PDF**, these **content streams are invalid** as the PDF specification explicitly requires balanced and properly nested marked content operators.

Comment: Now that was a very clear and good answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I used a commercial product and had no issues. Adobe Acrobat failed to extract anything.
Much of the underlying form text is an image, I did not extract that also but it could be with the coupled OCR engine. I assumed you only would want the text content and not the image OCR'd. If it was OCR'd and extracted to Unicode document, it would be fine.

[image]

Comment: True i only need to get the text from a C# wpf project. And that is my problem. It desnt seem to work no matter what i try.